# TypeError while searching through a list

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, typeerror, writefile

The project I am working on takes and opens the wiki homepage, opens every link on the page that is a Category, then takes the first 10 links on every category page and writes them to a file.

Code:

```
url_list = open('url_list', 'w')

counter = 0

urls = []

html = urllib.request.urlopen('https://commons.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page')

soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')

for item in soup.find_all('a'):
    urls.append(item.get('href'))

    for item in urls:

        if 'Category' in item:
            page = urllib.request.urlopen('https://commons.wikipedia.org/' + item)

            soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(page, 'lmxl')

            if counter < 10:
                for item in soup.find_all('a'):
                    url_list.write(item.get('href'))

                    counter += 1

url_list.close()
```

When I run the code I get this  TypeError:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/huntergary/Web_links.py", line 42, in <module>
main()
File "/Users/huntergary/Web_links.py", line 23, in main
if 'Category' in item:
TypeError: argument of type 'NoneType' is not iterable
```

Comment: You are using the name `item` twice, in the outer `for` and in the inner  `for`. That'll cause problems

Answer (score 1):

Check that an `'href'` item gets returned before appending it, or check `item` before trying to see if `'Category'` is in it:

```
href = item.get('href')
if href is not None:
    urls.append(href)
```

Or,

```
if item is not None and 'Category' in item:
```

Either approach should prevent you from checking against `None` objects in your `urls` list.

As a side note, you should consider not re-using the variable name `item` three times in a nested context like this. In the deeper layers of the code, it's not always clear which `item` you meant to refer to.

Comment: you can also do simply `if item and 'Category' in item`

Comment: @RafaelC True, though I'm not positive what the return types of `.get` could be. If they're anything besides `list` or `str`, e.g. if it could return an `int` or something else that might not behave nicely when directly converted to a bool. I knew he was getting `None`s, so I opted to just check for that explicitly